# Align two paragraph elements next to each other?

Tags: html, css

So I have a weird situation.  Setting up a page to generate labels for printout.

Here is what I currently have:

```html
<div class="rowoftags">
    <div class="col1">
        <p class="firstname">Jill</p>
        <p class="lastname">Smith</p>
        <p class="position">Web Developer</p>
        <p class="company">Company A</p>
        <p class="city">Denver, </p>
        <p class="state">CO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <p class="firstname">Jordan</p>
        <p class="lastname">Smith</p>
        <p class="position">Web Developer</p>
        <p class="company">Company B</p>
        <p class="city">Denver, </p>
        <p class="state">CO</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I move the paragraphs City and State next to each other with CSS so Denver, CO is on same line while other lines stand correct?

Comment: `p` is a block element. block element take the full horizontal space available. try changing display property to inline or inline-block for city and statement paragraphs.

Comment: display: inline worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Change p to span ,it is generate labels for printout

```html
<div class="rowoftags">
    <div class="col1">
        <p class="firstname">Jill</p>
        <p class="lastname">Smith</p>
        <p class="position">Web Developer</p>
        <p class="company">Company A</p>
        <span class="city">Denver, </span>
        <span class="state">CO</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <p class="firstname">Jordan</p>
        <p class="lastname">Smith</p>
        <p class="position">Web Developer</p>
        <p class="company">Company B</p>
        <span class="city">Denver, </span>
        <span class="state">CO</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works too.  But it would require modifying my python script to feed data :)

Comment: @RDudek ok then use display: inline-block using css

Comment: Yep, that worked.  Thanks!